# Iterate through list from any given starting point and continue from beginning?

Tags: list, loops, delphi

Iterating through a list is trivial. In this case, a `TCollection` property of a component I'm working on. I have no problem with iterating from `0` index to the maximum index - I've done it plenty of times.

However, I'm working on something now which needs to iterate a bit differently. I need to iterate through a list of collection items from any given starting point - and yet complete a full loop of all items. After the last list item, it shall automatically continue iteration from the beginning of the list.

To clarify: traditional iteration works like:

```
for X := 0 to SomeList.Count-1 do ...
```

But I may start it at some other point, such as:

```
for X := StartingPoint to EndingPoint do ...
```

And it's that "EndingPoint" which I cannot figure out. Iteration only increases. But in my case, I need to reset this current iteration position to the beginning - right in the middle of the iteration. `EndingPoint` might be less than the `StartingPoint`, but it still needs to do a complete loop, where once it reaches the end, it picks up from the beginning.

So, in a list of 5 items, rather than just going...

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

I may start at 2, and want to do...

```
2, 3, 4, 0, 1
```

How do I accomplish such a loop?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
for foo := 0 to Pred(SomeList.Count) do begin
  i := (foo + StartingPoint) mod SomeList.Count;
  ...
end;
```

Use the index `i` inside the loop; ignore the `foo` variable.

From the middle to the end of the range, `i` will equal `foo + StartingPoint`. After that, the `mod` operator will effectively make `i` "wrap around" to the start again.

Comment: Such perfect. Much appreciate.